# req.user is undefined when i start my server back up

Tags: node.js, session, cookies

Basically when I stop my server and start it back up, I check if I am logged in and I check if there is a user id attached to my cookie session. It always returns false. For some reason when I turn off my server the user id attached too my cookie session seems to be deleted. Is there any way to stop it from being deleted? I want to be able to turn my server off then turn it back on and have the connect.sid cookie contain a user.id allowing me to automatically be redirected as signed in.

Here is where I create my session:

```
app.use(session({
    secret: 'secret',
    saveUninitialized: true,
    cookie: { expires: new Date(253402300000000) }
}));
```

Here is where i attach a user id to the session:

```
app.post('/signin', passport.authenticate('local', {
    failureRedirect: '/',
    failureFlash: true
}),

function (req, res) {
    // If this function gets called, authentication was successful.
    // `req.user` contains the authenticated user.
    res.redirect('/');
});
```

Here is where I check if the user is logged in or not:

```
app.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
    var username;
    if (req.user || req.isAuthenticated()) {
        username = req.user.username
    } else {
        username = '';
    }
    res.render('StockPage/HomePage', { user: username });
    next();
});
```

Comment: You must persist your session store to disk, you can accomplish that by using some specific server such as Redis as answered right below by @Tuan. Express uses session in memory, if you turn the server down, it'll lose all the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default `express/session` use MemoryStore. You may want to take a look at a different [session store](https://github.com/expressjs/session#compatible-session-stores)

This one below is example with [connect-redis](https://www.npmjs.com/package/connect-redis)

```
var session = require('express-session');
var RedisStore = require('connect-redis')(session);

app.use(session({
    store: new RedisStore(options),
    secret: 'keyboard cat'
}));
```